# Query to insert custom taxonomy on posts

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I insert category in post which are inserted using `wp_insert_post()`.
I have tried the following but does not work.

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $category_ids, 'my_custom_taxonomy');
```